# Angular - Get <audio> element reference

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an audio tag in my template and I want to access [these methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_audio_play.asp) inside my component, cause I need functions for play and pause according to click events.

I tried the way below, but I can't access play() method. What is the correct approach?

TEMPLATE:

```
<div align="center" class="tela">
<div class="telaPlay" *ngIf="showPlay">
  <p>
    Qual é<br/>a<br/>Música?
  </p>  
  <a href="#"
    class="botao"
    (click)="novoJogo()">Play
  </a>
</div>
```

COMPONENT ...relevant...:

```
  play(): void {
    let player = document.getElementById("player");
    player.play();
  }
}
```

CAN'T ACCESS JS METHODS

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typecast element to HTMLAudioElement

```
function play(): void {
    let player = <HTMLAudioElement>document.getElementById("player");
    player.play();
}
```